# LED Monitor problems while connected to notebook with OS Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8

My new LED Samsung Monitor cannot be connected to my sony vaio laptop with OS windows 8.1 however it is working with the same laptop but with OS Ubuntu.
I also tried to update the drive but nothing works.
please inform me what can I do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Windows 8 and not Windows Phone- should probably be moved to SE SuperUser.

Comment: Have you pressed Windows+P to bring up the "project" dialogue, to select the external monitor?